# Increase margin between ul-li menu and Selected Menu

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation menu in which the `li` are very much close to each other. how to increase the `margin-left` between the menus. i tried it in `.main_menu li` but its not working.
and also how to add `selected` to a menu. i.e. on click of the menu it should have properties similar to `:hover`(black background and blue text)

**Here is a fiddle:** [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5s2mQ/2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `display:inline` with `display:inline-block` and add `margin-left` that you want inside class `.main_menu li`
Try this:

```
.main_menu li {
    display:inline-block;
    padding-left:1px;
    font:bold;
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5s2mQ/8/)

Comment: how the selected menu item wil work? i want on selection it should have properties similar to `:hover` (black background and blue text)

Comment: you can create a class like: .selected where you put your css and add the class to the element selected @vishalkin

Comment: i tried [this](http://jsfiddle.net/5s2mQ/25/) and added `.selected` besides `:hover` ?

Answer (score 2):

Add `margin-left` to `a` instead of `li`: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5s2mQ/10/)

Answer (score 1):

see this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/5s2mQ/5/)

use `inline-block` instead of `inline`.

```
.main_menu li
{
    display:inline-block;
    padding-left:1px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    font:bold;
}
```

Inline elements dont have a 'box' layout, so margin will not apply. 
But block elements (or inline-block elements) do.

Answer (score 0):

Change your display type to `inline-block` and then the margin property will work.

```
.main_menu li {
display:inline-block;
padding-left:1px;
font:bold;
margin-left:10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5s2mQ/14/

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the `a` would do the trick.
Probably you would want to align it too.

```
/* the margin part so the buttons won't touch eachother */
margin-left: 10px;
margin-top: 2px; /* optional, you only asked for the left */
/* to align: */
width: 18%;
float: left
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5s2mQ/24/